# Angular $compile misbehaving when returning value

Tags: angularjs, templates

I'm trying to use Angular `$compile` to compile my template.

My template looks like this:

```
var template = '<div>{{obj.someValue}}</div>';
```

I'm showing my data in another ctrl/view:

```
$scope.obj.someValue = "hi";
$scope._html = '';

<div>{{html}}</div>
```

Now at some point I render my template.

```
$compile(template)($scope);
$scope._html = template;
```

**At this point I'm confused.** Because `template` hasn't changed.

So I tried the following:

```
$scope._html = $compile(template($scope);
```

**This does work and compile the template correctly, but my entire console is flooded with errors:**

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
at Sa (angular.js:265)
at r (angular.js:319)
```

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Do not expect the contents of `template` to mutate when you use it with `$compile` - your second usage is correct. As for the console-related error, you might be seeing a [browser-specific bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12004).

Comment: I'm now actually running the $compile on the `.contents()` result of an element. That seems to work...